# Calling two different windows on click of two different Check boxes, one followed by other in netbeans gives Exception

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Here are two functions for check boxes

**CheckBox : ActiveBox**

```
private void Active_BoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (Active_Box.isSelected() == true) {
       Active_Link.main(args);
    }
}
```

**Check Box :SQLBox**

```
private void SQL_boxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (ESC_box.isSelected() == true) {
       ESC.main(args);
    }
}
```

**Active.java**

```
public class Active extends Application { 
private final Node rootIcon=null; 

TreeItem<String> rootNode = new TreeItem<String>("My Workflows");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage stage) {
    rootNode.setExpanded(true);
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
       reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\onlyForms.txt"));

       String line=null;

       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           if (line.indexOf("Checking") >= 0) {
               String next=reader.readLine();
               if(next.contains("Passed_qualification ")) {
                  TreeItem<String> depNode = new TreeItem<String>(line)              
                  depNode.setExpanded(false);
                  TreeItem<String> depNode1 = new TreeItem<String>(next); 
                  depNode.getChildren().add(depNode1);
                  String next1=reader.readLine();
                  TreeItem<String> depNode2 = new TreeItem<String>(next1);
                  depNode.getChildren().add(depNode2);
                  rootNode.getChildren().add(depNode);
               }
               if(next.contains("Failed_qualification ")) {
                  TreeItem<String> depNode = new TreeItem<String>(line);
                  depNode.setExpanded(false);
                  TreeItem<String> depNode1 = new TreeItem<String>(next); 
                  depNode.getChildren().add(depNode1);
                  String next1=reader.readLine();
                  TreeItem<String> depNode2 = new TreeItem<String>(next1);
                  depNode.getChildren().add(depNode2);
                  rootNode.getChildren().add(depNode);
        }
        stage.setTitle("Escalations");
        VBox box = new VBox();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(box, 500, 500);
        scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
        box.setStyle("-fx-font: 18 arial;"); 
        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(rootNode);
        box.getChildren().add(treeView);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**SQL.java**

```
public class SQL extends Application { 
  static String str=null;

  static  String next_line=null;

  static BufferedReader br;

  private final Node rootIcon; 

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {           
     launch(args);

  }

  public SQL() {
      this.rootIcon = null;
  }

  public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    rootNode.setExpanded(true);

    BufferedReader reader=null;

    try
    {
      FileInputStream f=new FileInputStream("D:\\SQL\\SQL_XML_TXT.txt");
      reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f));
      String line=null;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {   
         if (line.indexOf("TID") >=0) { 
           String next1=reader.readLine();
           String next2=reader.readLine();
           String next3=reader.readLine();
           String next4=reader.readLine();
           String next5=reader.readLine();
           String next6=reader.readLine();
           String next7=reader.readLine();

           String time_date=SQL.GetTime(br);

           if(((next7.indexOf("OK"))<0)) {
              if(((next7.indexOf("SQL Trace Log- ON"))<0)) {  
                TreeItem<String>depNode=new TreeItem<String>(line);
                depNode.setExpanded(false);
                TreeItem<String> depNode1 = new TreeItem<String>(next1); 
                depNode.getChildren().add(depNode1);

                TreeItem<String> depNode2=new TreeItem<String>(next2);

                depNode1.getChildren().add(depNode2);

                TreeItem<String> depNode3=new TreeItem<String>(next3);
                depNode1.getChildren().add(depNode3);

                TreeItem<String> depNode4=new TreeItem<String>(next4);

                depNode1.getChildren().add(depNode4);   

                TreeItem<String> depNode5=new TreeItem<String>(next5);
                depNode1.getChildren().add(depNode5);

                TreeItem<String> depNode6=new TreeItem<String>(next6);

                depNode1.getChildren().add(depNode6);  

                TreeItem<String> depNode7=new TreeItem<String>(next7);

                depNode1.getChildren().add(depNode7);  
                rootNode.getChildren().add(depNode);
              }

            } 
          }
      }

   }        
   stage.setTitle("Escalations");
   VBox box = new VBox();
   final Scene scene = new Scene(box, 500, 500);
   scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
   box.setStyle("-fx-font: 18 arial;");
   TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(rootNode);
   box.getChildren().add(treeView);
   stage.setScene(scene);
   stage.show();
  }
}
```

When i click on two check boxes one follwed by other, first window will open and when i click on another check box it throws following exception

> "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called
>   more than once  at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:137)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:118)
>   at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:241)

Comment: @All, please revert me in case any clarifications

Comment: "Some Code Logic" is missing here. There has to be `javafx.application.Application` somewhere in your code(probably you extend `Application` somewhere). That part is completely missing. If you hope to get an answer, please give us more code. (by the way, I'm pretty sure the code you left in the `main` functions is not the part that is relevant to the problem)

Comment: @fabian, Can you make out something from this, I have sent complete code, what i have done till now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to call `javafx.application.Application.launch` multiple times. This leads to your exception. If you want to create a new window, just create a new `Stage` and add the new content to this stage (since you are creating the windows from Swing, you have to do this from the JFX thread; see last code snipplet):

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
// add your content here
stage.show();
```

If you still want to have `SQL` and `Active` as possible entry points of your Application I'd recommend writing methods that basically do the same as your `start` methods (minus the Stage part) but return the `Scene` object, e.g. something like this:

```
public class Active extends Application {

    public static Scene createScene() {
        Scene scene = //... insert your code here

        return scene;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(createScene());
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

and change the CheckBox function like this:

```
private void Active_BoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (Active_Box.isSelected() == true) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> { // invoke "Runnable" from JFX thread
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(Active.createScene());
            stage.show();
        });
    }
}
```

and do the same for the SQL part.

If you don't need `SQL` and `Active` to be entry points, you don't need to extend `Application` of course...